# submit multiple values from a textfield with the same name

Tags: php

i have a form, the carries two textfields with the name attributes "name" and "amount"

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="name" value="wole" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="amount" value="100" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="yetunde" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="amount" value="200" size="32" required="required" />
</form>
```

my intention is to capture name and amount side by side in two rows, based on how my form is structured.

i have tried submittin the data into the database using this snippet

```
$sql="INSERT INTO records(name,  amount)VALUES('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[amount]')";
```

but it only submits one row of data, "wole and 100", how can i make sure i capture the two different rows from my form

Comment: You must rename your vars, there must only be 1 name. HTML doesn't have arrays, but you can try with something like name[1], name[2] and then parse it in php.

Comment: i dont know how to go about this, can u explain using the snippet i have given

Comment: Happy SQL Injections!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, here is the full code.
I added a new field "score" to show you how to add new fields.

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" name="studentname[]" value="wole" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="course[]" value="100" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="score[]" value="100" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="studentname[]" value="yetunde" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="course[]" value="200" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="score[]" value="100" size="32" required="required" />
</form>


<?php
$con=mysqli_connect
("localhost","root","famakin","results");
//Checkconnection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo"FailedtoconnecttoMySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
foreach($_POST['studentname'] as $idx => $studentname) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO records(studentname,  course, score)VALUES('" . $studentname . "', '" . $_POST['course'][$idx] . "', '" . $_POST['score'][$idx] . "')";
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error:'.mysqli_error($con));
    }
}


echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=result.php">';
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: and what about the amount

Comment: "amount" has to be defined to accept multiple values using "[]" too. $_POST[amount][$idx] will take care that you store the right amount for the current "name"

Comment: i am getting this error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Then you most certainly have an error in your HTML code. Make sure the form field are named "name[]" and "amount[]".

Comment: i corrected the error, and i only get a row, with the name captured but for the amount i get array[]1

Comment: please edit your code above or post a link to a phpfiddle or something like this, so that we can find the problem.

Comment: Please correct this: $_POST[course][$idx] should be $_POST['course'][$idx]

Comment: can u please do a sample with just two fields and two table columns and ill take it from there

Comment: I just saw, that you call mysqli_query outside the foreach loop. I edited your pastebin: http://pastebin.com/yabjnbxU

Comment: works like charm, thanks alot, but finally if i needed to a new field column can u please edit the paste bin to show what i would do. e.g i wanted to add score to my form and pass it to my datbase

Comment: i also think u shud update wat u have here, for others who would be looki for such solution

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use square brackets with form element names:

```
<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="100" size="32" required="required" />
```

in such a case you will receive an array of values in your `$_POST['amount']` and then you are responsible for parsing it properly and inserting as many rows as you want, e.g. with `foreach` php loop or like.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array notation in names

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="wole" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="100" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="yetunde" size="32" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="200" size="32" required="required" />
</form>
```

in php you can get theses as

```
   $_POST[amount][index_no_here];
```

Eventually you can put it in loop to alter for each index

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it might be best to just use an array of fields. If it absolutely has to be one field, you could just split the string into an array by some separator (comma, semi-colon, etc) in your business layer and then loop through it to create different records in the database.