# PHP/JQuery and HTML how to submit multiple cloned forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hello i have this code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function($){
            $countForms = 1;
            $('.myForms').submit(function () {
                console.log("");
                return true;
            });

            $(function(){
                $("#clickMe").bind("click", function(){
                    $(".myForms").trigger('submit');
                });
            });
            $.fn.addForms = function(){
                var myform =
                    "<fieldset>"+
                    "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'  class='myForms'>"+
                    "<label class='label_ga' for='artikel("+$countForms+")'>Omschrijving gewenst artikel:"+
                    "<input class='input_ga' name='artikel["+$countForms+"]'  type='text' value='' size='30'></label><br>"+
                    "<label class='label_be' for='bewerking("+$countForms+")'>Omschrijving gewenste bewerking:"+
                    "<input class='input_be' name='bewerking["+$countForms+"]' type='text' value='' size='30'></label><br>"+
                    "<label class='label_aa' for='aantal("+$countForms+")'>Aantal:"+
                    "<input class='input_aa' name='aantal["+$countForms+"]'  type='text' value='' size='30'></label><br>"+
                    "<label class='label_kl' for='kleur("+$countForms+")'>Kleur:"+
                    "<input class='input_kl' name='kleur["+$countForms+"]'  type='color' value='' size='30'></label><br>"+
                    "<label class='label_op' for='opdruk("+$countForms+")'>soort opdruk:"+
                    "<select class='select_op' name='opdruk["+$countForms+"]'  size=''30>"+
                    "<option>borduren</option>"+
                    "<option>bedrukken</option>"+
                    "<option>voorzien van eigen logo of uitdruking</option>"+
                    "</select></label><br>"+
                    "<label class='label_fi' for='file("+$countForms+")'>Afbeelding:"+
                    "<input class='input_fi' type='file["+$countForms+"]' name='foto'    value=''    size='30'/></label>"+
                    "</form>"+
                    "</fieldset>";

                myform = $(myform);
                $("button", $(myform)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });

                $(this).append(myform);
                $countForms++;
            };
        })(jQuery);

        $(function(){
            $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(){
                $("#container").addForms();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">


   <button id="clickMe">send</button>

</div>

<button id="mybutton">Artikel Toevoegen</button>
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Artikel Toevoegen" name="add"/>

</body>
</html>
<?php
//if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $count = count($_POST['artikel']);
    echo $count;

foreach ($_POST["artikel"] as $artikel) {
//    echo $artikel;
    print_r($_POST["artikel"]);
}
//}
?>
```

this is a short testing script.

can someone please help me and tell me how i can make one button that submits the forms.
and the information from the form is accesible by the php code in the end so i can send it by mail(i allready have this code for one form)

Hope someone can help me thanks

Comment: Do you want to submit all of the forms at the same time?

Comment: yes i need to send all the information to a email adress at the same time but that part is in my other code wich doesnt clone the form i wil add that part later when i have this part working

Comment: What is not working? You're not doing anything with your submit to know if it is working or not.

Comment: the submit button didnt work so i commented it

Comment: Why not just submit one form and collect the values as an array like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020764/submit-multiple-values-from-a-textfield-with-the-same-name